# Parse Cloud Code syntax differences causing failed query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, parse-server

We require an aggregation pipleline that will use multiple stages such as: `addFields`, `lookup`, `group` and `unwind`. When converting the working syntax in the MongoDB compass to a parse cloud code javascript call, we are not getting the same results.

The exported "Node" code from MongoDB compass is as follows:

```
[
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'user': {
        '$substr': [
          '$_p_pUser', 6, -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': '_User', 
      'localField': 'user', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'userobject'
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'username': '$userobject.username'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$username'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$username', 
      'total': {
        '$sum': '$score'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

There are some notable syntax differences between the raw mongoDB query and what is required for calls from parse server. The syntax, converted to something that should work (to the best of my knowledge) is as follows:

```
var pipeline = 
    {
        addFields : 
        { 
            user : '$pUser.objectId', // different from the above syntax. This is how the object id of the user is accessed
            username: '$userobject.username'
        },
        lookup : {
            from: '_User',
            localField: 'user',
            foreignField: '_id', // although most calls from the parse server aggregate pipeline should access "_is" instead by "objectId", in this case it seems the lookup table has a field name "_id" and not "objectId"
            as: 'userobject'
        },
        unwind : { path: '$username' },
        group : {
            objectId: '$username',
            total : {
              $sum : '$score'
            }
        }
    };
    var pipelineResults = await gameTableQuery.aggregate(pipeline);
```

## Expected Output

The expected output is to match the current table's user pointer (`pUser`) with the User table. Then to group by username, while finding the sum of scores.

## Actual Output

In the above case when searching for the `_id` in the the lookup stage, there are 0 entries returned.

In the case where the lookup stage foreignField is replace by `objectId`, every user instead of only the user that is matching the local field.

```
lookup : {
    from: '_User',
    localField: 'user',
    foreignField: 'objectId',
    as: 'userobject'
}
```

There seems to be some syntax error occurring that is lost in translation between the MongoDB syntax and the parse server aggregate pipeline syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a failing test like

```
fit('order by pointer', (done) => {
    const pointer1 = new TestObject({ value: 1});
    const pointer2 = new TestObject({ value: 2});
    const pointer3 = new TestObject({ value: 3});

    const obj1 = new TestObject({ pointer: pointer1 });
    const obj2 = new TestObject({ pointer: pointer2 });
    const obj3 = new TestObject({ pointer: pointer3 });
    const pipeline = [
      {
        project: {
          tempPointer: { $substr: [ "$_p_pointer", 11, -1 ] }, // Remove TestObject$
        }
      },
      {
        lookup: {
          from: "test_TestObject",
          localField: "tempPointer",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "tempPointer"
        }
      },
      {
        unwind: {
          path: "$tempPointer",
        }
      },
      { sort : { "tempPointer.value" : -1 } }
    ];
    Parse.Object.saveAll([pointer1, pointer2, pointer3, obj1, obj2, obj3]).then(() => {
      const query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);
      return query.aggregate(pipeline);
    }).then((results) => {
      expect(results.length).toEqual(3);
      expect(results[0].tempPointer.value).toEqual(3);
      expect(results[1].tempPointer.value).toEqual(2);
      expect(results[2].tempPointer.value).toEqual(1);
      console.log(results);
      done();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      done();
    });
  });
```